# Android best practice to handle UI during a network call

Tags: java, android

I want to know what is the best way to handle a UI during a network call. For example -

I have a login screen with login button and email and password input fields. I enter email and password fields and press login button. I show a progress dialog. I subscribe now with RxJava and I have my observer in presenter. He tells the view to show a progress dialog. The API call is in progress. Stil my observable has not returned anything back. Now I press back button and my progress dialog is dismissed. I again press login button and a second call is done. So I can do this repeatedly and queue my requests.

What is the best practice to handle this scenario where user is allowed to make one request per once button click? I know there are several ways to do it in view such as greying out the button or using a progress bar which is non dismissable. But I am more interested in knowing how to deal this scenario in my model layer. I want my view to be as dummy as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why not override `onBackPressed` to cancel any in-progress threads?